# Available branch name vars in merge

Tags: git, git-merge

I'm trying to do a config command for merging branches. I see there are some vars available like $BASE $LOCAL AND $REMOTE
These vars contain the name of the file followed by the base, local, remote string.

Are there any variables that contain the name of the branches for these 3?

Comment: Aren't there only 2 branches involved? (branch you're merging & branch you're merging into)

Comment: actually there are 3 branches and files. The third file comes from the ancestor branch (common branch from which these two split somewhere on the line) of these two you mentioned. Yes, it is not needed the ancestor's name.

Answer (score 0):

Refs are available pointing to those commits - `ORIG_HEAD` and `MERGE_HEAD`. [This script](https://gist.github.com/mrenouf/1247554) shows how to get a suitable name for them, although those commits may well have more than one name:

```
WORK_LOCAL="$WORK/$(git name-rev ORIG_HEAD | cut -d' ' -f 2)"
WORK_REMOTE="$WORK/$(git name-rev MERGE_HEAD | cut -d' ' -f 2)"
```

you could also use `git describe --all ORIG_HEAD`.

Edit: see [`this page`](http://www.davesquared.net/2009/02/setting-up-diff-and-merge-tools-for-git.html) for an example of how to set up a `mergetool` under Windows. To use DiffMerge, if your sample command line is correct, you would omit the `mkdir` and `cp` commands and replace the line:

```
meld "$WORK_LOCAL/${FILE}" "$OUTPUT/${FILE}" "$WORK_REMOTE/${FILE}"
```

with:

```
"C:/Program Files/SourceGear/Common/DiffMerge/sgdm.exe" --title1="$WORK_LOCAL = Current branch" --title2="$BASE = Common ancestor" --title3="$REMOTE = Merging branch" /m /r="$MERGED" "$LOCAL" "$BASE" "$REMOTE"
```

Comment: But how can I incorporate this into .gitconfig file? I am the point where I wrote this 

cmd = \"C:/Program Files/SourceGear/Common/DiffMerge/sgdm.exe\" --title1=\"\"$LOCAL\" = Current branch\" --title2=\"\"$BASE\" = Common ancestor\" --title3=\"\"$REMOTE\" = Merging branch\" /m /r=\"$MERGED\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$BASE\" \"$REMOTE\"

Comment: You'll need to write a wrapper script like the one I linked to. Or, for Windows, something like [Setting up a merge tool](http://davesquared.net/2009/02/setting-up-diff-and-merge-tools-for-git.html).

Comment: Thanks. I have Windows. The source You gave me does the same thing as the line I provided, in a different approach.

I was looking for something like this: let's say i have a branch named `better_interface` and another one named `master`, when I open diffmerge it should show in the left `better_interface` and in the right `master`, not the name of the file. 
Thanks.

Comment: Okay, so you know how to get at this information in a `mergetool` script. So you're really asking how to get DiffMerge ([this DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/)?) to show extra information aside from just the filenames during a merge?

Comment: Yes, that diffmerge. Extra information for my need is the branch name.